# HP Zbook Windows 10. Fan runs on high speed when powered off. Unable to access BIOS. Tried F keys and boot to UEFI

Tags: bios, fan

Computer given as a Christmas present 5 days ago. Won't enter BIOS to access fan settings. Have tried all of the F keys and Esc key. Have gone to Recovery and told it to restart at UEFI Firmware screen. Can't get it to work.

Comment: New computer. Under warranty.   Contact HP Support

Comment: Does DEL not work on laptops